# tomar una sola palabra de varias repetidas en un select con php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

tengo la siguiente duda:
en una base de datos tengo bajo el nombre categoria lo sigiente:
miselaneas
php
html
html
al hacer un select me muestra las cuatro palabras, lo que preciso hacer es que si una palabra esta repetida me la muestre solamente una vez para poder armar una lista, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Podrias hacer un distinct o un group by por el campo que necesitas, si pasas mayor informacion sobre la tabla que indicas podria asesorarte un poco mejor

Comment: perdon no se cargo el codigo:

esto seria el php:

<ul>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM articulos";
$data = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
while ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
echo"<li class='toggle'>".$c['categoria']."
<ul class='ul'>
<li>".$c['titulo']."</li>
</ul>
</li>";
 };
?>
y la base de datos esta conformada asi
id
titulo
descripcion
contenido
subido
fecha
categoria

Comment: haz click en [edit] para agregar el código a la pregunta. lo pegas lo seleccionas y das CTRL+K y se tabula

Answer (score 6):

Esto se puede hacer o bien en la consulta a la base de datos o bien en el array:

En la base de datos has de poner:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM xxxxxx WHERE zzzzz = yyyy
```

O bien en un array PHP usando **array_unique()**:

```
    $entrada = array(0 => "verde", 
                     1 => "rojo", 
                     2 => "verde", 
                     3 => "azul", 
                     4 => "rojo");

    $resultado = array_unique($entrada);

    print_r($resultado);
```

El resultado sería...

```
    Array 
   (
    [0] => verde
    [1] => rojo
    [3] => azul
    )
```

Tienes más ejemplos y descripción en: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php

---

**Para arrays multidimensionales**

Lo normal es que la consulta te traiga un array multidimensional, entonces aquí hay un pequeño script que utiliza **array_search()**.

Hilo en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650892/array-unique-for-multidimensional-arrays

```
    $matrix = array(
    0 => array(0 => '123', 1 => 'aaa'),
    1 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    2 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    3 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    4 => array(0 => '114', 1 => 'aaa'),
    5 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    6 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    7 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    8 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'aaa'),
    9 => array(0 => '124', 1 => 'baa'),
    10 => array(0 => '123', 1 => 'baa'),
    11 => array(0 => '1241', 1 => 'baa'),
);


$d = array();
foreach ($matrix AS $key => $value) {
    if (!array_search($value, $d)) {
        $d[] = $matrix[$key];
    }
}

var_dump($d);
```

Devuelve:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '123' (length=3)
      1 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '124' (length=3)
      1 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '114' (length=3)
      1 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '124' (length=3)
      1 => string 'baa' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '123' (length=3)
      1 => string 'baa' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1241' (length=4)
      1 => string 'baa' (length=3)
```